# Bash - extract substring between 2 characters

Tags: bash, substring, text-extraction

Strings may be as follows:

```
1cd9f3e7d...7b486fef4 lineage-15.1-caf-8952 -> github/lineage-15.1-caf-8952  (forced update)
8648766e0..6e7faf655  lineage-15.1-caf-8952 -> github/lineage-15.1-caf-8952
e60d05ad9..784fbae86  lineage-15.1 -> github/lineage-15.1
b651b35..673d421  lineage-15.1 -> github/lineage-15.1
0a5232e..a36e212  lineage-15.1 -> github/lineage-15.1
f94851a03e2..d2ff869bdf6  lineage-15.1 -> github/lineage-15.1
769dd0439..88d4d3adc  lineage-15.1-caf-8952 -> github/lineage-15.1-caf-8952
a0553bd5f1a..69748ff0d0f  lineage-15.1 -> github/lineage-15.1
dbe2868..ab03f89  lineage-15.1 -> github/lineage-15.1
7caf61f4e..2de89a8d9  lineage-15.1 -> github/lineage-15.1
```

I need to extract string between `.` abd `l` characters. If I execute sed on each of above strings:

```
awk -F"[.l]" '{print $3}'
```

Result - first string is empty:

```
6e7faf655  
784fbae86  
673d421  
a36e212  
d2ff869bdf6  
88d4d3adc  
69748ff0d0f  
ab03f89  
2de89a8d9
```

If I do this like this:

```
awk -F"[.l]" '{print $4}'
```

Result - first substring is fine, the rest are shifted:

```
7b486fef4 
ineage-15
ineage-15
ineage-15
ineage-15
ineage-15
ineage-15
ineage-15
ineage-15
ineage-15
```

How to deal with it to get always substring as I want, with no matter what is source string format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\.\.)\w+' file 
7b486fef4
6e7faf655
784fbae86
673d421
a36e212
d2ff869bdf6
88d4d3adc
69748ff0d0f
ab03f89
2de89a8d9
```

Comment: This is simplest syntax, thanx

Answer (score 1):

Choose one you like:

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/^[^.]+\.{1,}([^.[:space:]]+).*/\1/' file
```

---

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ sub(/.*\.{1,}/, "", $1); print $1 }' file
```

---

The output:

```
7b486fef4
6e7faf655
784fbae86
673d421
a36e212
d2ff869bdf6
88d4d3adc
69748ff0d0f
ab03f89
2de89a8d9
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify OP's attempt

```
$ awk -F'[.]+| ' '{print $2}' ip.txt
7b486fef4
6e7faf655
784fbae86
673d421
a36e212
d2ff869bdf6
88d4d3adc
69748ff0d0f
ab03f89
2de89a8d9
```

- `-F'[.]+| '` field separator is consecutive dots or the space character. So, getting second field is enough

  - can also use `-F'[. ]+'` here

Answer (score 1):

`cut -d ' ' -f 1 FILE | rev | cut -d '.' -f 1 | rev`

Explanation:

- First `cut` extracts first part (till the first space).
- Than we are using `rev` so each line is reversed so last field is now first one.
- Than we are using `cut` again to extract first column till `.` character.
- At last `rev` again to restore proper order of characters.